# android webservice axis2 stub

Tags: android, web-services, apache-axis, stub

im trying to learn about web services and i already did a simple webservice (sayhello) and made a client that show a console message. To do this... i made a webservice client that generate a stub.

Now i need to consume this service from an android application.
Without read nothing i cutted the both files (stubs) and paste in my android proyect... and thist told me that is impossible to resolver org.apache.axis2.

Probably its doesnt work like that, but i dont know if is possible to do in this way or what is the orther or others ways to do.

Someone know something about and can help me??

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tutorial on how you can use to get you up and running in terms of what you want to achieve:

- [How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) - this one takes it a bit further in showing you how to connect to production databases and consume web services.

You can actually get some insights from it. Hope it helps.